# NEST 7.X DateHistogram Interval is deprecated, proposed alternative returns 400

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I started with NEST 7.x to query ES and there is a warning message for DateHistogram **interval** property, because of the deprecation.

Here is the code that works fine, although I am getting warning message in Visual Studio about deprecation of the `Interval`

```
.Aggregations(ag=>ag
                .DateHistogram("daily",g=>g
                    .Field("Created")
                    .Interval(DateInterval.Day)
            ))
```

VS offers two other options which are `CalendarInterval` or `FixedInterval`
Using either of them results in 400 response

> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.. Call: Status code 400 from: POST /qa-reporting-2020%2A/_search?typed_keys=true. ServerError: Type: illegal_argument_exception Reason: "[date_histogram] **unknown field [calendar_interval]**, parser not found" ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request

Do you know what will be the solution?

Comment: You're likely using a version of the client that supports `CalendarInterval` and `FixedInterval` but an Elasticsearch version that does not. You can suppress the deprecation warning in Visual Studio with a pragma directive e.g. `#pragma warning disable 0618` and restore on line after

Answer (score 0):

I see it is also not working in Kibana when querying ES. It will be due to the older version of ES which does not know about this new option as mentioned here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html